# Using angular-cli build artifacts as dependency of other angular2 project

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

Is there any way to use the build artifacts in other angular-cli project?
For example, I created project "A" built it and published. Then I have created project "B" and added A to its dependencies (node_modules).
Currently this is the artifacts of project A:
[image: 111.png]
Lets say that Project A has some components I want to use in project B, how can I do it - is it even possible with the current cli version?

I have also posted this question on the [github page of the project](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2732).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question makes little sense. What exactly do you trying to achieve with that? Faster resource compilation?

As your projects have different dependencies and those bundles build by combining dependencies into single files it's not going to be reusable between projects with different dependencies. But you also mention that you going to list one project as a dependency of another. So all dependencies of project A will be needed by project B. It can be considered as a possible optimisation but build artefacts do not belong in source control, so it's not a common scenario.

And after all, if you can read about [AoT Compilation for Angular2](http://slides.com/wassimchegham/demystifying-ahead-of-time-compilation-in-angular-2-aot-jit#/) (especially tree-shaking) to understand steps in the direction you thinking about that offered by Angular2 team.

Comment: I am trying to build a library which other cli based projects can later consume as a 3rd party dependency

Comment: Is your library going to be compatible only with those versions of dependent libraries you bundle it with? So if some of your users will have problems with those dependencies versions they will need to abandon your lib or wait for you to release new version?

Comment: It would be few components. There won't be any dependencies other then angular's

Comment: Once again. What are you trying to make? Lib with prebuild angular in it? No one going to use that as it'll automatically block users from getting newer versions of angular at moment of release.

Comment: If you mean prebuild that it won't contain the code it's depends on then yes. For example angular material 2, they are not shipping their library with all its dependencies, right?

Comment: AngularMaterial2 is a good example. They just don't ship any build artifacts. Nor should you do. As it not going to benefit your users in any way. Because of the reason I mention in my answer.

Comment: Ok, but what should I do in my project (B) so project (A) could import its modules (components)?

Comment: Include dependencies into your project `package.json`?

Comment: Project B is already in project's A package.json dependencies. What exactly I need to do next? How can I import and use project B components? Sorry if I am asking silly questions - I am new on this topic and there is not much reference on the web.

Comment: Project B `project.json` need to contain all project B dependencies. When project A include project B both `project.json` files will be processed by npm. Total list of dependencies will be build on top of that.

Comment: OK... Should I add project B module in project's A bootstrap imports?

Comment: Of course. That's how other libs works for you, why your approach for your own lib need to be different? All that can spare you not writing additional code is best for a final result.

Comment: Cool. Here is a lib I found on github https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination. As you can see he creates a dist directory with all the compiled files. Also he creates a name space for his library ng2-pagination. Why is he generating a dist file?

Comment: I guess it's just his mistake (he forget to add dist to .gitignore file). Because contents of this dir is generated by https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination/blob/master/webpack.config.js and you can recreate it by running webpack at any moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125861/discussion-between-vlio20-and-sergey-moiseev).